# Look up value in data frame from a single vector

Tags: r, merge, match, vlookup, lookup

I have tried different things here but not getting my desired results. What I am trying to do is use a vector `v1 <- 22201691`  look up this number from a two row df. Then fill the data from `df1$NC2` in another vector Output

df1

```
RFC        NC2
22294961   239
22200691   239
22201691   239
22701619   344
22717619   344
```

What I want to do is use v1 to look up and match `df1$RFC` and my output would be `df1$NC2`. So in my example my_output = 239

Here is what I tried:

```
#this worked sometimes but not all the time.
Output<- df1[(1:dim(df1)[1])[df1[,1]==v1],2]  

#no luck with this one  
vlookup_Output <- function(){
df1%>% 
filter(NC2 %in% c("RFC", "NC2")) %>% 
pull(v1) }
```

I have also tried to use the merge functions but being that `v1` is a number, trying to merge `df1` didn't work either.

Like always thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: df1$NC2[df1$RFC %in% v1]

Comment: Thanks this worked, but here the problem I have. So my v1 vector is pulled from another data.frame. When I do str(v1) it is num, but when I run the script it comes out as numeric(0). Now if I manually type in the number for v1 it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
my_output <- df1$NC2[df1$RFC %in% v1]
```

If the value comes from another dataframe, then:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(22201691))

df1$NC2[df1$RFC %in% df2$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but here the problem I have. So my v1 vector is pulled from another data.frame. When I do str(v1) it is num, but when I run the script it comes out as numeric(0). Now if I manually type in the number for v1 it works perfect.

Comment: @BentlyBartee, if the value is in a column of another dataframe, you can do as suggested in my updated answer.

Comment: @BentlyBartee you're welcome! You can also accept the answer as helpful if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `tidyverse` solution, here it is.

```
library(dplyr)

vlookup_Output <- function(DF, x, col, out){
  DF %>% 
    filter(get(col) %in% x) %>% 
    pull(out) 
} 

v1 <- 22201691
vlookup_Output(df1, v1, "RFC", "NC2")
#[1] 239
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(RFC = c(22294961L, 22200691L, 22201691L, 22701619L, 
22717619L), NC2 = c(239L, 239L, 239L, 344L, 344L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, but here the problem I have. So my v1 vector is pulled from another data.frame. When I do str(v1) it is num, but when I run the script it comes out as numeric(0). Now if I manually type in the number for v1 it works perfect.

Comment: @BentlyBartee Are you sure you don't have factors?

Comment: I am not sure. I checked the data.frame v1 is coming from with str() and the column I selected is a num.

Comment: @BentlyBartee I cannot reproduce what you are saying. I have just tested it with `v1` as numeric, character and factor and it always works.